# Match html tags that has anything in the middle

Tags: javascript

I have below regex to match a tag

```
str.match(/<xsl:template(.+?)xsl:template>/g);
```

But problem is if I have newlines in between those two tags, it's not matching anything. So I am preparing string like this before

```
str = str.replace(/(\s{2,}|\t)/g, ' ').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
str.match(/<xsl:template(.+?)xsl:template>/g); // Now it matches.
```

I have tried to merge it into one regex like below

```
str.match(/<xsl:template(.+?|\r\n|\n|\r)xsl:template>/g);
```

But it does not work. Please help me to tweak this `/<xsl:template(.+?)xsl:template>/g` regex to match anything between tags.

The possible duplicate question in comments does not answer my question.

Comment: Have you tried using an XML parser instead?

Comment: No I have not tried. It does not fit my requirement. My actual requirement is to fix custom formatted xml string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Claudiu That answer says its not good to parse html tags because text format could be anything. My question is pretty straight forward and I know that string is not malformed. For everything if thats the answer, most of the regex questions are invalid in SO

Comment: You might have to add a little to your question about your situation, your exact requirements, and why you can't use an XML parser. You assert that you know that the string is not 'malformed', but no regex will match [something like this](http://sprunge.us/DNZA) correctly, despite it being perfectly good XSL.

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider just using an XML parser. It handles this and far more (like [@Wander Nauta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999464/match-html-tags-that-has-anything-in-the-middle/38000091#comment63444306_37999464) pointed out). You will run into issues if you don't. Just fix it now!

You said it does not fit your requirement. It does. You want to manipulate an XML string. This is exactly what XML parsers are for. You parse it, then you manipulate the *returned data* structure which *represents* the XML. Then you dump it back out.

---

That being said, to answer this specific issue with this specific regex: `.` doesn't match newline characters. However, `\s` does (all whitespace characters, actually). And `\S` matches non-whitespace characters. So use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`:

```
> str = "foo <xsl:template> some stuff\n in my \ntemplate</xsl:template> "
> str.match(/<xsl:template(.+?)xsl:template>/g);
null
> str.match(/<xsl:template([\s\S]+?)xsl:template>/g);
["<xsl:template> some stuff
 in my 
template</xsl:template>"]
```

Comment: Have tried DOMParser, but it throws error if there is `xsl:template` tag in it

Comment: @Exception: Hmm then you're receiving invalid XML documents. This works fine, for example: `var parser = new DOMParser(); parser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">foo <xsl:template> some stuff\n in my \ntemplate</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>'`

Comment: Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tyfqnkd/2/). if you see the xml doc there, its invalid because `xsl-template` is missing for few elements. So thats why I am applying logic to add xsl:template on orphan elements. Please suggest if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, you really shouldn't parse html tags as text, unless you can guarantee the formatting, because you need to cover every possibility. The previous comments are right.

However, if you must, the simplest way to do it is this (avoiding CR/LF/whitespace/tab etc):

```
str.match(/<[^>]*xsl:template([^>]+)xsl:template[^>]*>/g);
```

This relies on the one thing you can guarantee with html as text - that tags begin and end with less than / greater than symbols. The 'not greedy' ? shouldn't be necessary as the match ends as soon as it hits the end tag marker.